# How can I download files from UIWebView using ASIHTTPRequest?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, webkit, asihttprequest

I want to create a section of my app where you can download the current webpage showing in the UIWebView and then save it to a UITableView and when you tap on the filename in the UITableView, it will load the local file in the UIWebView to allow offline browsing.

How can I do this with http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest? I've taken a look and all the code looks very daunting for a beginner! Is there an alternative method? Is this the best method?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ASIWebPageRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest) is the answer. It's a class included with ASIHTTPRequest that makes it easy to download whole pages, with all their associated dependencies.

You'd probably want to create a custom cache to store your downloaded webpages in, and then load them out of that cache when requested by the user.

Comment: would I be able to have some sample code as I am a beginner? Thank you so much! :-)

Comment: Yes but it's not all for what I need to do and I don't know what to use and what to not use :(

Comment: This is an ambitious app idea for you, then. I salute your fortitude. You will learn much.